# Side image overlapping top image for frame

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a border that consists of images, one per side, and 4 different, one per corner. The outcome is not as expected. The left and right sides of the border are overlapping top and bottom sides. In addition, corners are not visible as they are covered by the sides. Below is the code that I have so far.

```
<div class="book-border" style="margin: 5%">
    <div class="book-top"
         style=" margin: 1%; background: url(style/border_br.png) bottom right no-repeat,
                    url(style/border_bl.png) bottom left no-repeat,
                    url(style/border_tr.png) top right no-repeat,
                    url(style/border_tl.png) 0 0 no-repeat,
                    url(style/border_right.png) top right repeat-y,
                    url(style/border_left.png) top left repeat-y,
                    url(style/border_bottom.png) bottom left repeat-x,
                    url(style/border_top.png) 0 0 repeat-x;">

        <h2>New Books</h2>
        //Some HTML code
    </div>          
</div>
```

How I can achieve a clear border that corners will be visible and will not overlapped by the rest?

**UPDATE:**

I have a new CSS file that contains background styling but still can't achieve what I would like.

```
<div class="book-category" id="newbooks">
        <h2>New Books</h2>

</div>
```

//CSS

```
 div.book-category{
        margin:10px;
        padding:10px;
        background: url("style/border_tl.png") 0 0 no-repeat,
        url("style/border_left.png") 0 0 repeat-y, 
        url("style/border_right.png") top right repeat-y,
        url("style/border_top.png") 0 0 repeat-x,
        url("style/border_bottom.png")  bottom left repeat-x;
    }
```

The outcome is

[image]

Comment: Do the corner images have alpha transparency? Does the element have variable width and height (and is that essential)?

Comment: Corners they do not have alpha transparency. How I can order so the corners apply last? Is just the way you have them in 'background'?

Comment: not sure but why dont you do it in the css. `border-left:your stuff; border-top:your stuff; border-right:your stuff; border-bottom:your stuff;` this way you can change each border to your wishes

Comment: Please add a screenshot showing what's wrong, or add a link to a demo (using an online service like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)). It looks like the bg images are already in the right order (the images listed first go on top, in this case the corners).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe stating the obvious but could you just use a CSS border?

```
.book-top { border: 1px solid black; }
```

If you require image based broders then I would combine all your images in to a single background image and give the element some padding so that you can see the background image at the edges.

Multiple background images never usually work as expected and are very difficult to use.